# How to I count the frequency of an array (PHP)

Tags: php

I am beginner in php

How to count the frequency of Score and put it in a table in descending order of a score?

array = 15, 17, 17

```
+-------------+-----------+
|    Score    | Frequency |
+-------------+-----------+
| 17          | 2         |
| 15          | 1         |
+-------------+-----------+
```

I have this problem for more than a week, I already tried the array_count_values but it print all values in one row.

Comment: how did you use `array_count_values`? please illustrate its output and how you want it to be.

Comment: hi, you can edit your question to show the result of `array_count_values`, so we can differentiate and mold it with what you want.

Comment: sorry I am beginner in php
echo '
<tr>
<td>'.array_count_values($myarray).'</td>
<tr>
';
and it says Notice: Array to string conversion in .......
help me please

Comment: it's because you are trying to print an array. you should loop on that array. `array_count_values` returns an array, please read: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: last time I used that, it print all values in one row but now It says Notice: Array to string conversion

Comment: Can you print_r($myarray) and attach the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that something like this, using krsort() instead of arsort(), would give the desired output:

```
<?php
$array = [15, 17, 17];
$scores = array_count_values($array);
krsort($scores);  // This will order it by score descending.

echo "<table>\n";
echo "<tr><th>Score</th><th>Frequency</th></tr>\n";
foreach ($scores as $value => $count) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $value . "</td><td>" . $count . "</td></tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve it with `array_count_values()` like I have below.

```
<?php
   $array = [15, 17, 17];
   print_r(array_count_values($array));
```

This will output the following - the value and the count.

```
Array
(
    [15] => 1
    [17] => 2
)
```

A better use case for your situation would be this (If output in HTML):

```
<?php
    $array = [15, 17, 17];
    $scores = array_count_values($array);
    krsort($scores);  // Order array by score descending.

    foreach ($scores as $value => $count) {
        echo $value . ": " . $count . "<br/>";
    }
```